# Express returns an error but Promise.allSettled is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, middleware

I am using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to create a simple api server. I am mainly doing this to practice my understanding of async/await and asynchronous code in javascript.

Here is my json-server start code that seeds the db and api code:

```
module.exports = () => {
    const data = { documents: [] }    
    for (let i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
        data.documents.push({ id: i })
    }
    console.log('done');
    return data
}
```

Now I can hit GET - /documents (returns all documents)
GET - /documents/id (returns a document via the ID).

I want to practice Error handling with async await, so I made middleware to return an error if the id is 4:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {       
  if(req.originalUrl.split('/')[2] === '4') {      
    return res.status(429).send({error: 'rate limit exceeded'})
  };
  next()
}
```

The API structure appears to work as I intended. However, when I use Promise.allSettled to process an array of promises, the promise that returns an error has the error object as a value, but the status still says "fulfilled".

```
const getById = async (id) => {
    try {
        const data = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/documents/${id}`);    
        return data;

    } catch (e) {
        return e
    } 
}   



( async () => {
    try {
        const resolvedPromises = await Promise.allSettled([
            await getById(1),
            await getById(2),
            await getById(3),        
            await getById(4)
        ]);        
        console.log(resolvedPromises);
    } catch(e) {
        // THIS RUNS IF I THROW THE ERROR FROM getById, however Promise.allSettled stops 
        // execution.
        console.log(e);
        console.log('error');       
    }
    
})()
```

Here is the output when I run the code above:

```
[
  {
    status: 'fulfilled',
    value: {
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    status: 'fulfilled',
    value: {
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    status: 'fulfilled',
    value: {
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    status: 'fulfilled',
    value: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 429] {
      message: 'Request failed with status code 429',
      name: 'AxiosError',
      code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      response: [Object]
    }
  }
]
```

Why is the status `fulfilled` vs `rejected` when I call `await getById(4)`?
Is this an issue with the value I'm returning from the express server?

Comment: Remove the `await` before each `getById()`, that's just slowing your code down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.allSettled` is not being passed an array of promises: the `await` operators in

```js
const resolvedPromises = await Promise.allSettled([
            await getById(1),
            await getById(2),
            await getById(3),        
            await getById(4)
        ]);
```

are executed when the parameter value to pass to `allSettled` is being evaluated before making the call. Since `await` throws if its promise operand becomes rejected, the `catch` clause of the surrounding `try/catch` is executed as noted in the question.

Leaving out the `await` operators before the calls to `getById` may solve the issue, assuming `getById` calls never synchronously throw before returning a promise.

---

Looking more closely `getData` is an async function and so won't throw on being called. It is also *fullfilling* its return promise with an error object if the `axios` call rejects. If you want the promise to be settled in a rejected status, you could

- rethrow the error in the `catch` clause within  `getById`,
- remove the `try/catch` block from within `getById`.
- return the axios promise from `getById` by reducing it to

  ```
    const getById=id=> axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/documents/${id}`);
  ```

Comment: …and then, `return e` can be replaced by `throw e` (or just omitting the `try`/`catch` altogether) in `getById`

Answer (score 1):

About this part here:

> THIS RUNS IF I THROW THE ERROR FROM getById, however Promise.allSettled stops execution.

Because your code is equivalent to this here:

```js
try {
  const tmp = [];
  tmp[0] = await getById(1);
  // wait for getById(1) to finish
  tmp[1] = await getById(2);
  // wait for getById(2) to finish
  tmp[2] = await getById(3);
  // wait for getById(3) to finish
  tmp[3] = await getById(4);
  // wait for getById(4) to finish
  
  // and if any one of these promises is rejected, 
  // the code goes straight to `catch` and never even reaches the following line.

  const resolvedPromises = await Promise.allSettled(tmp);
  console.log(resolvedPromises);
} catch (e) {
  // THIS RUNS IF I THROW THE ERROR FROM getById, however Promise.allSettled stops 
  // execution.
  console.log(e);
  console.log('error');
}
```

These `await`s are not only slowing your requests down, by running them in series instead of paralell, they are **breaking** your code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> catch (e) {
>   return e
> }
> ```

Catching the error and returning a value turns that rejected promise into a fulfilled one.

Remove the `try..catch` and everything will work as expected (once you also implement the suggestions in [traktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73381633/283366))

```js
const getById = (id) => axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/documents/${id}`);
```

If you did want to catch failures (eg for logging), ensure you keep the resulting promise rejected

```js
// async / await
try {
  return await axios.get(url);
} catch (err) {
  console.error("request failed", err.toJSON());
  throw err; // re-throw
}

// .then() / .catch()
return axios.get(url)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("request failed", err.toJSON());
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
```

See also

- [Promise.reject()](https:////%20see%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)
- [Handling Errors | Axios Docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)

Comment: What is the `err.toJSON()` method?

Comment: @Bergi part of Axios' error object. It removes cyclic references and makes debugging much easier