# Why can't I return data after await a promise object in async function

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie studying coding.
I tried to mock mysql database query, so I followed below code(https://techhelpnotes.com/node-js-mock-database-jest-using-ts-jest-utils/)

//database.js

```js
const getDbConnection = () => {
  const pool = mysql.createPool(DB_CONFIG);
  return {
    query : function (sql) {
      return util.promisify(pool.query).call(pool, sql);
    };
```

//controller.js

```js
try {
  let result = await db.query(sql);
  res.status(200).json(result);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(DB error, error);
}
```

It worked for me, but I thought I could return the query with await by using it in databse.js like the one below

```js
query : async function(sql) {
  try {
    return await util.promisify(pool.query).call(pool, sql);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(DB error, error);
  }
}
```

so I thought I can use query function without error handling

```js
let result = await db.query(sql);
```

But it doesn't work. What difference is there between the two codes that makes the above code work and the below now??

Many thanks!

Comment: `console.log(DB error, error);` is invalid syntax. Did you make the same typo in your *actual* code? (if so, that's why)

Comment: FYI the `mysql2` package supports promises natively

Comment: Catching an async exception (aka a rejected promise) without re-throwing it or returning `Promise.reject()` will make your function resolve (successfully) with an `undefined` value (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73381590/283366)). This moves extra logic into the calling code. IMO, just don't do it; stick to your original version

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I didn't use the console.log(DB error, error) in my actual code. I thought that was just a pseudo code. 

Thanks Phil. After looking through your comments and link, I could see what was wrong :-)